# Theoretical paper was rejected by the editor due to no experimental data: Is this common?

Tags: experimental, publishing

This may be a sensitive question that may cause theoretical scientists to feel injured.

Today my paper was rejected after assigning it to the editor. Here is what the editor said about the reason:

> "With your manuscript, in absence of experimental data supporting the
> theoretical predictions, I am sadly unable to conclude that the work
> represents a clear conceptual and methodological advance that would
> likely generate interest among our readership. The paper is better
> suited for a broad-topic journal focused on hypothesis-driven
> research, without any evaluation of immediate impact."

My question is whether the theoretical data are just something that must follow the experimental data. Are predicted data meaningless without experimental data?

Comment: I already had the same justification to reject a manuscript I submitted. The funny thing was that came from the editor of a pure theoretical journal.

Comment: @AnoopANair do you have experience on Academia.SE? It is totally ***not*** the place to ask a question like this, which is specific to experimental/theoretical matter modeling. It's a site for academia in general meaning there's history majors and music majors there.

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes I do understand that! But then the users question is on "whether the theoretical data are just something that must follow the experimental data. Are predicted data meaningless without experimental data?" how can such a question be answered with appropriate citations to articles. It seems too broad for the Matter Modelling SE. Apart from that, the presence of History and Music major won't hinder the theoreticians there from answering such a question ;)

Comment: @NikeDattani Actually, I think it's a general enough question that it'd be fine to post on AC.SE. In fact, I think there are some related questions there already. And the Academia demographics is definitively skewed towards mathematics, computer science, and the natural sciences. Still, I think the question fits here too.

Comment: @Anyon the user made the same type of comment (now deleted) on [this question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3880/5), which I'm afraid may have negatively impacted the fate of that question. Have you ever seen a Q with a net score of 9, and an answer within 1 day with a net score of 15, which never once entered the HNQ list? HNQ is where we get 99% of our traffic and new users joining (see the number of new users after we get a question in HNQ), and it is often the difference between a question getting 200 views vs 2k views. We can be more careful in telling people to go away!

Comment: @AnoopANair Here's another reason why it's okay to ask these questions here rather than on Academia.SE, you can see in this chat room that there's several feeds pointing Academia.SE users to other sites that have questions about academia in their own specific field: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/the-ivory-tower

Comment: Here is a highly influential purely theoretical paper that may be used as an example for an answer to the actual question asked: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.63.054416 It is the prediction of the TMR effect in Fe | MgO | Fe sandwiches. One could say that this paper guided experiments.

Comment: For the record: The question as it stands (“Are predicted data meaningless without experimental data?”) would certainly not be suitable for Academia SE, because it is about the contents of a specific field. The answer is different for different fields and depends on the epistemology of those fields (not the academic culture). The right audience for such a question are experts in the field you are asking about (which you hopefully find here), not any broader selection of academics. (CC@AnoopANair)

Answer (score 15):

This all depends very much on the journal. It is not necessarily something that should make you "feel injured", since there's many journals that allow for the publication of theoretical calculations that are completely devoid of experimental support.

This specific wording that the editor used:

> "The paper is better suited for a broad-topic journal focused on
> hypothesis-driven research, without any evaluation of immediate impact"

makes it appear that the journal to which you submitted, prefers to publish papers that will have "immediate impact" rather than papers that generate a hypothesis to be tested later by experimentalists. Furthermore the beginning of the editor's message:

> "With your manuscript, in absence of experimental data supporting the
> theoretical predictions..."

indicates to me that this journal prefers to publish work that is experimentally supported.

***Examples of journals in our field that are like this include JACS and Angewandte Chemie***, the former being notorious for not publishing work in theoretical chemistry without experimental support. However "International Journal of Quantum Chemistry" and [THEOCHEM](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-molecular-structure-theochem) do publish a lot of papers that are purely theoretical (however you have not told us which journal you're discussing, so it's hard to tell whether or not you're a molecular matter modeler or a materials matter modeler: based on your other questions it looks like you work more in the solid-state side of things, meaning that you'd be looking more at physics journals than chemistry journals, so "Physica Status Solidi B" might be a journal for you to consider).

> "My question is whether the theoretical data are just something that
> must follow the experimental data. Are predicted data meaningless
> without experimental data?"

It absolutely does not have to follow experimental data, and it is absolutely *not* "meaningless" without experimental data, *however* a trap that a lot of middle-scale academics fall into is that they think that because they solved a challenging problem that involved a lot of work, it should be publishable in a good journal. Unfortunately there's millions of challenging problems that we can get students to solve, which will be of very little interest to other people, so if a journal wants to maintain its reputation as one of the "most cited" or "most viewed" journals in the field, it often has to choose only the most "impactful" or "widely interesting" papers to publish. Now especially in our field of matter modeling, a lot of theoretical results are in fact meaningless from an experimental standpoint (*not* meaningless altogether, because by telling the reader what a certain method predicted under the conditions of the calculations, it still says something meaningful about the *method*) because you can get numbers with DFT (for example) that are just completely wrong. Many journals will not be interested in publishing such results, which is why journals catering *specifically* to theoretical work (e.g. International Journal of Quantum Chemistry or THEOCHEM) were created to let theoreticians have a place to put their results.

Finally I'll say that many editors get a ***large volume*** of papers each day, and it's not uncommon for them to give generic rejection letters that are made to look polite and personal but really are copied and pasted. If you see your question's edit history, you might notice that you made a lot of grammatical errors just in writing this question alone, and if your paper looked anything like that, the editor might (based on the writing quality alone) not have wanted to waste the time of the referees, since it's not always easy to find senior academics that are willing to volunteer their time towards reviewing a (poorly written) paper for free. So if you see lots of theoretical papers in that journal, without experimental support, consider that your paper just didn't meet the journal's quality standards.

I will also end with what are I wrote at the end of [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/3885/5):

> "It usually does no harm to look at some of the papers in the most
> recent issue of a journal, and even write to the editor an informal
> inquiry about the suitability of the journal for your paper, before
> formally submitting the paper, since this can save you the loss of
> time (and energy and enthusiasm!) associated with having a paper
> rejected."

By doing this you can see in advance whether or not the journal accepts papers without experimental support.

I would recommend next time also to tell us ***which journal*** you're discussing, and if you don't mind even showing us the paper we can help you a lot more than you might have originally thought.

Comment: This nice answer discusses several points that surely are of relevance here. I think another point may be finding the right words in the letter to the editor, the abstract, the introduction and/or the conclusion of the work. In the end the editor has to see the potential value of the work and if he doesn't see it it may be because you were not explicit enough, not finding the best context, or not thinking big enough.

Comment: I agree that the editor prefers high impactful manuscripts. Before choosing any journal, I checked if the journal has published any paper using DFT related to the field I am concentrating on. My results are new and haven't published in any literature. I knew my English isn't good. Before submitting, the grammar, spell, notations, etc were checked more than 20 times before my co-authors made double-checks. So it is not a 'poor written' paper. I also think the experimental editor just read the cover letter and abstract only. That's why I believe it's likely unfair.